# What is the dual space of $C([0,T];X)$ ($X$ Hilbert space)?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems

What is the dual space of  $C([0,T];X)$, where $X$ is a Hilbert space? Is it $\operatorname{BV}([0,T]; X^*)$?

As we know, for $C([0,T])$, the dual space is $\operatorname{BV}([0,T])$,  but when it is continuous with vector values in $X$, is it still true?